# Async calls of several WCF WebServices

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I have a console application that runs a loop calling 4 WCF Web Services in a specific order.

Each iteration of the loop is not dependent on the previous or the next iteration.

Each iteration of the loop takes about 5 seconds.

I would like to use some parallel or async work to get this time down.

Basically, what I am thinking is that while I am waiting on one of the services, I could be getting another iteration calling one of the other 4 services.

However, in my attempts, this has not worked.

I have tried to do something like this:

```
dataRows.ToList().ForEach(async patientRow =>
{
     // Calls made here.  Example calls below:
     var personData = await personOperations.SavePersonAsync(personRow);

     var saveResponse = await orderingBrokerOperations
                                 .SaveAsync(orderedTestContracts, personData);

     printOperations.Print(saveResponse );
});
```

But this ends up front loading tons of the calls.  (Meaning that the 1st web service gets blasted with many many requests.)  Eventually one of the calls times outs because it is getting too many requests.

So then I tried this:

```
Parallel.ForEach(dataRows,
         new ParallelOptions{MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10}, (patientRow) =>
{
     // WCF calls are made synchronously
});
```

This kept my calls from going overboard, but did not really increase the speed much.

I also tried  doing this

```
Parallel.ForEach(dataRows,
         new ParallelOptions{MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10}, async (patientRow) =>
{
    // Do the calls here.  Each call is made using the await keyword.
});
```

but it had the same problems as the first option.

Out of frustration I then tried this:

```
long inProgress = 0;
dataRows.ToList().ForEach(async patientRow =>
{
    inProgress++;
    if (inProgress > 10)
       Thread.Sleep();

    // Do the calls here.  Each call is made using the await keyword.

    inProgress--;
});
```

This did not really speed things up either.

My Dev Servers are not really strong, but they should be strong enough to handle at least 10 calls at the same time.  I am not sure what is going on.

**Is there a good way to spread out the calls to my services without running synchronously?**

Comment: The part you've elided with "do the calls here" is actually pretty important. Could you please put in the shortest code possible that still replicates the problem you're describing?

Comment: `async` does not initiate or help parallelism. This might be a misunderstanding of yours.

Comment: Besides using `Parallel.ForEach` for I/O-bound ops being wrong... passing `async void` method/lambda anywhere an `Action` can be accepted is a very common error. I almost think there should be a compiler warning for this.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/05/10278165.aspx) implementation of `ForEachAsync` by Stephen Toub. It should enable you to do what you want and it allows control of how many tasks you want to execute concurrently.

I would also recommend making your WCF calls asynchronous if possible. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623922/different-forms-of-the-wcf-service-contract-interface) post for more detail.

On a final not if you want to execute many async operations concurrently, you do not `await` them as you are kicking them off. You store each `Task` in a list as they are being kicked off and then you used `Task.WhenAll` to `await` their completion.