# How to determine whether Task.Run is completed within a loop

Tags: c#, task

This may be an odd question and it is really for my educational purpose so I can apply it in future scenarios that may come up.

I am using C#.

I am stress testing so this is not quite production code.

I upload data to my server via a web service.

I start the service off using a `Task.Run`.

I check to see if the `Task` is completed before allowing the next Run.Task to begin.

This is done within a loop.

However, because I am using a modular declared `Task` will not the result be affected?
I could declare a local `Task.Run` variable but I want to see how far I can get with this question 1st.

If the `Task.Run` can raise an event to say it is completed then this may not be an issue?

This is my code:

//module declaration:

```
private static Task webTask = Task.Run(() => { System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents(); });
```

//in a function called via a timer

```
if (webTask.IsCompleted)
{
   //keep count of completed tasks
}


webTask = Task.Run(() =>
{
    try 
    { 
         wcf.UploadMotionDynamicRaw(bytes);  //my web service
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //deal with error
    }
);
```

Comment: Use [Task Continuation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372288%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). There are different modi. One of them is *do something after the task has finished*. IMO you don't need the timer - change your code to `webTask.ContinueWith...`.

Comment: @pasty HI, thanks for aquick response. I will look at this now and report back - thanks :)

Comment: @pasty so when I amend my code to this:

Comment: webTask = new Task(wcf.UploadMotionDynamicRaw(bytes));

Comment: It gives me an error 'cannot convert from 'void' to 'Action'?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

IMO you do not need the timer. Using [Task Continuation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372288%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you *subscribe* to the **done** event:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task
.Run(() => 
{
    // simulate processing
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("do something {0}", i + 1);
    }
})
.ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine("done."));
```

The output is:

```
do something 1
do something 2
.
.
do something 9
do something 10
done
```

Your code could look like this:

```
var webTask = Task.Run(() =>
{
    try 
    { 
        wcf.UploadMotionDynamicRaw(bytes);  //my web service
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //deal with error
    }
}).ContinueWith(t => taskCounter++);
```

With task continuation you could even differentiate between *failed* and *success* process result, if you want to count only successfull tasks - using the [TaskContinuationOptrions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcontinuationoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Hi, I was using the timer just for stress testing and completely agree with you. The example on MSDN is different to yours and I prefer yours. Much clearer.  Thank You

Answer (score 3):

You can wait for your task to complete by awaiting your task like this

```
await webTask;
```

that will asynchronously wait for 'webTask' to complete. Instead of the timer you can use `await Task.Delay` which will asynchronously wait for the delay to expire. I would also consider making the  wcf call asynchronous so you don't have to call inside `Task.Run`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22931546/1239433) for some tips.

I'd rewrite the code as follows:

```
public async Task UploadAsync()
{
    while(true)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000); // this is essentially your timer

        // wait for the webTask to complete asynchrnously
        await webTask;

        //keep count of competed tasks

        webTask = Task.Run(() =>
                        {
                            try 
                            { 
                                // consider generating an asynchronous method for this if possible.
                                wcf.UploadMotionDynamicRaw(bytes);  //my web service
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                //deal with error
                            }
                        });     
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the different answer. Much appreciated. I was aware of the await but i wanted to have async. The reason for all this is to monitor whether the web server is keeping up with my repetitive calls. By monitoring the queue I can (hopefully) detect this.