# Why does this sync wrapper over an async method work?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

Given:

- A legacy non-async API method on an ASP.NET/WCF web service
- New async internal library
- New async Web API controller that should be used going forward
- A "storage provider" object that only has an async interface. Its tests pass when run asynchronously, and when run synchronously outside a request context.

The option "go async all the way" is not on the table, since it would break backward compatibility.

```
public class Impl {
    // This works fine when used asynchronously
    public Task<Guid> SaveThingAsync(Thing thingToSave) {
        return await _storageProvider.saveAsync(thingToSave);
    }

    public Guid SaveThing(Thing thingToSave) {
        // "Obviously", this code creates a deadlock when called 
        // from within the request context
        // return SaveThingAsync(thingToSave).Result

        // Not so obviously, this also creates a deadlock
        // return SaveThingAsync(thingToSave)
        //            .ConfigureAwait(false)
        //            .GetAwaiter()
        //            .GetResult()

        // This was deadlocking, but magically stopped
        // return Task.Run(
        //        async () => await SaveThingAsync(thingToSave)
        //                      .ConfigureAwait(false)
        //               ).Result;

        // This one works
        var saveTask = Task.Run(async () => 
                            await SaveThingAsync(thingToSave)));
        var result = saveTask.ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        return result;
    }
```

Why?

Answer (score 1):

`Task.Run` steps "outside" the request context - it just runs on the thread pool context. So, it won't deadlock because `SaveThingAsync` doesn't resume on the request context.

On a side note, the `ConfigureAwait(false)` is meaningless there, since there is no `await` to configure.

On another side note, "async all the way" should still be an option. WebAPI and WCF clients *don't care* whether the implementation they're calling is synchronous or asynchronous. Changing a WCF method implemented synchronously to a WCF method implemented asynchronously is invisible to client code.

Comment: Well, that's annoying. Yesterday I was getting TaskCancelled exception when running the first `Task.Run` example. Since our clients don't just use a direct service reference, but instead a client library generated from our interfaces, changing the SOAP interface would break everything.

Comment: @Eris the client can't tell as Stephen mentioned. This is not a compat problem. This is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22591516/122718

Comment: @Eris: The first (commented out) `Task.Run` example is really, *really* weird. It bends my brain trying to figure out what it would do. Passing around `ConfiguredTaskAwaitable` structures is not idiomatic. You should be able to use your own (asynchronous) interface in the server instead of the synchronous interface consumed by the clients - unfortunately, this would (logically) duplicate the interface description.